# Is there any shortcut for Bold or codeblock in Markdown editor in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, markdown, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide

I'm writing a tool's wiki and I have a need for a shortcut to set some words in Bold or codeblocks instead of writing ` / ** or clicking the Bold/codeblock button as you can see in this example:

[image: Bold button]

Is there any shortcut for setting words to Bold in the Markdown editor for JetBrain's IDE such as PyCharm?

If not, does anyone have a macro that solved this and is willing to share it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign preferred shortcuts to these actions in **Settings | Keymap**, **Plug-ins | Markdown**

[image]